# Webpack use one module throughout different files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I currently have my js files layed out as such

- file.js
- anotherFile.js
- anotherFile2.js
- db.js

I want to be able to include the `db.js` in `file.js`,`anotherFile.js` and `anotherFile2.js`. Do I need to import `db.js` into every single file or is there a way that I can import it once to be used throughout the project.

`file.js` imports `anotherFile.js` and `anotherFile2.js` but all use `db.js`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to import `db.js` into every single file...

That's best practice, yes. More specifically: You import the parts you need from it. (Don't worry, it's only loaded once.) Otherwise, you're back in the land of globals everywhere, which is what modules are intended to help you avoid, because the global namespace is crowded and conflicts are easy to run into.

You *could* create globals in `db.js`, load it from `file.js`, and have `anotherFile.js` and `anotherFile2.js` rely on those globals, but it's strongly discouraged. Explicit relationships between modules don't only help the browser, IDE, and bundler; they help the programmer, too.